# How to call a method present in @PostConstruct class

Tags: java, spring, postconstruct

I have class `MyModel.java` and I'm constructing it using `@PostConstruct`.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test")
public static class MyModel extends Model {

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
    }
}
```

Now I want to call a method of Model class(contains field and getter setter) say:

```
сlass Model {

    ....
    //fields and getter setter

    public void testValues(){
    }
}
```

Now I want to call `testValues()` in `@PostContruct` .

How can I call it ?

Comment: Do you mean that you'd like to call a method that is present on the super-class? Then you'd just do this within `postConstruct()`: `testValues();`, as any other method in a hierarchical state would

Comment: I dont want to call within postconstruct().  as Model class is loading in postconstrct so we can call it from Model class.

Comment: @Saiprateek can you clean up the question a bit? what you are writing in question is contradicting with what you wrote here ( *Now I want to call testValues() in @PostContruct* vs *I don't want to call forn annotated method* ).  And what you asked is also hard to understand: *" as Model class is loading in postconstrct"* Model class is loading what? "*we can call it from Model class*" Call from which place?  Do you mean you want spring to invoke some method in `Model`, after all `@PostConstruct` annotated methods (in child and `Model`) are finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of the Spring bean's life cycle, `afterPropertiesSet()` will be called after `@PostConstruct` method, you can look [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-combined-effects), so you can use `afterPropertiesSet()` to call your `testValues()` as shown below:

**MyModel class:**

```
public class MyModel extends Model implements  InitializingBean {

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        //set your values here
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        testValues();
    }
}
```

I have added the below notes from the link on spring bean's lifecylce:

> Multiple lifecycle mechanisms configured for the same bean, with
> different initialization methods, are called as follows (emphasis is mine):
>
> Methods annotated with @PostConstruct **(called first)**
>
> afterPropertiesSet() as defined by the InitializingBean callback interface **(called after @PostConstruct method)**
>
> custom configured init() method **(called after afterPropertiesSet method)**

Comment: As Model.java class is loading in postconstruct so I don't want to call forn annotated method, I want to call from same class Model.

Comment: Can you add briefly on what are you doing inside postconstruct for the Model? Are you setting some values?

Comment: Yes..you can see in Model class there are some fields and there getter and setter methods which is initialising in postconstruct.

Comment: I got your point now and you can use afterPropertiesSet() as explained above